# footer overlap on content

Tags: html, css, 960.gs

I have an HTML structure like this :

```
<div id="content" class="container_12">
    <div id="right" class="grid_3 alpha">
        <div id="menu_right"></div>
        <div id="adv"></div>


    </div>
    <div id="main_c" class="grid_9 omega">s</div>


</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

but content overlaps on footer , I tried  but nothing happened.

here is the CSS :

```
#footer {
    border-top: 4px dashed white;
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    background-image: url("bannerbg.jpg");
}


#menu_right, #adv { width: 100%;
    min-height: 300px;
    background-color: #e3e3e3;
    margin-bottom: 10px;

    }


#main_c{
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #e3e3e3;
}
#content{
   // its blank
}
```

and it shows like this : 
[image: like this]

what should I do ? I tried clear:both between content and footer :-?

Edit : view this online , http://barcodes.ir/sap

Comment: where is your .container_12 ?

Comment: its 960.gs grid system , RTL one... not changed

Comment: This remainds me to... [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10174996/footer-wont-center-on-the-bottom-of-the-page/10175246#10175246). It's the same, the only difference is that you have the same problem in a desktop (instead of just a smartphone) because the center is bigger. Answer: Sticky footer. Google it.

Comment: Try adding `overflow: auto` to `#content`. I'm wondering if the columns are being floated and your `.container_12` isn't sorting that out properly.

Comment: view this online http://barcodes.ir/sap/ , thank u

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the css positioning, maybe you should try relative position in the footer.

See [this link](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/) to learn more information about positioning.

Comment: I used position: realtive for footer , and it didn't work , however thank you for your link... I'm reading that

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution: add `z-index: 1000;` like this to the #footer css set of rules. Like this:

```
#footer{
    z-index: 1000;
    ...
    ...
}
```

Your z-index must be higher than any other content. Apparently those boxes have higher z values, so you need to rebase them.

Comment: dear lu1s I need to extend content's height automatically . z-index doesn't seem to be my solution... thank you

Comment: I think he wants the footer to 'clear' the content; not simply appear in front of it.